# How to change background color/image in Ctrl+Alt+Delete menu?

Tags: colors, windows-11, ctrl-alt-delete, background

Is there any way to change a background color/image in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> menu?

After logon I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and see a menu with "Switch User", "Change a password", etc. options on a black background. My PC is running Win 11 Home. On other computers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> menu is shown on a dark blue background. But google can find pictures of this menu on a black background too (search "ctrl alt del menu"), so this is not a problem of my setup only.

Comment: I am 90% sure this comes down to the selected theme. Have you tried changing it?

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, i tried both dark and light themes and custom theme. I have one user with dark mode colors and the second user with default light theme. Both users have the same black background in Ctrl+Alt+Del menu.

Comment: Screenshots would be helpful

Comment: @Ramhound, here it is: https://technoresult.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/remove-lock-option-from-ctrl-alt-del-screen-fm.jpg.webp

Comment: I think your system is quite normal. I have the simplest possible theme on my computers and all produce a black screen with Ctrl Alt Del.

Comment: @John, strangely, but on a computer on my work the background color is dark blue, and it has Win 11 installed. The single difference is that it is not a Home edition. Maybe this is a reason, but if it is true I think there should be some registry key to handle this color.

Comment: I use Ctrl Alt Del so rarely that I just use what is there. Nothing to be concerned about and I would not hack the registry to change it,

Answer (score 0):

It is black in Windows 11 and I don't think you can change it. In Windows 10 and 8 you can change it, and it the colour set by your theme (Settings > Personalisation > Colours)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1226218)

Comment: Well it does. You can't change that colour on Windows 11